# Getting a continuously increasing ID from one XML-file to another

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis

In general terms, i've got the following situation:
A database consists of, say, 3,000 files. Each file in average consists of 500 structurally identical nodes. Top-parent element "Document" of each node  has an unique ID (non numeric).

**Task:**

- Document and all its childs/subchilds within Document's node have to get an additional, numeric ID (incrementing counts Document's node).
- The ID must have an assignable start range. ID increments with step +1. (Like 350001, 350002, etc)
- (the most essence of the question) ID-counter continues to work not only at the level of one XML file, but with the whole set of files.

> ```
> like:
> 01-file.XML (getting ID started from 35000001 with step 1
>             (ending, for exmpl, with ID 350002222
> 02-file.XML (ID starts from 350002223... etc
> ```

Maybe, i think, my question implies not my exact code in detail, but the request for a model of methods or a set of abstract patterns for solving described situation.

- I would appreciate any solutions suggested using exclusively XSLT language.
- Or, as an alternative or a complementary way - via SSIS-tools.

**UPD**: *My Thanks to Martin Honnen for 3.0 solution!*

**UPD**: *in addition i would appreciate if there are any XSLT 1.0 solution*

**UPD**: *Or via other integrated non-xslt SSIS-tools*

Comment: So which database is that? Which XSLT processor can it use?

Comment: The database consists of XML files. But you can ignore that this is a database and forget this word. All that matters is that it is a sequence of XML files with which a number of manipulations are necessary. The question is - to what extent can this be done exclusively within the XSLT language, cyclically from file to file.

Comment: any standart XSLT processor from vol.1 to vol.2.0

Comment: or if some solutions may come only from 3.0 - i would  welcome and this variant too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 3 you can do it using `xsl:iterate` and an accumulator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="documents" as="document-node()*">
        <xsl:iterate select="1 to 5">
            <xsl:document>
                <root>
                    <xsl:iterate select="1 to 5">
                        <section>
                            <xsl:iterate select="1 to 20">
                                <foo>foo {.}</foo>
                            </xsl:iterate>
                        </section>
                    </xsl:iterate>
                </root>
            </xsl:document>
        </xsl:iterate>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="start-id" as="xs:integer" select="35000"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="element-count" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="*" select="$value + 1"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:iterate select="$documents">
            <xsl:param name="start-id" select="$start-id"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="start-id" select="$start-id" tunnel="yes"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:next-iteration>
                <xsl:with-param name="start-id" select="$start-id + accumulator-after('element-count')"/>
            </xsl:next-iteration>
        </xsl:iterate>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:param name="start-id" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="collection-count" select="$start-id + accumulator-before('element-count')"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ8LVs

For self-containedness, that example generates the sample documents inline, but of course it is meant to be run with XSLT 3 starting with the initial-template (e.g. Saxon 9.8 or later command line option `-it`) and some setting of the `documents` parameter to e.g. `collection('?select=*.xml')` or some other way to initialize the collection of documents you want to process.

And of course outside that tool, you would want to generate separate result documents so have

```
  <xsl:result-document href="{document-uri()}-update.xml">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
            <xsl:with-param name="start-id" select="$start-id" tunnel="yes"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:result-document>
```

instead of

```
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
            <xsl:with-param name="start-id" select="$start-id" tunnel="yes"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
```

A way to run it with Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 and option `-it` and the source documents specified with `uri-collection` would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="input-uris" select="uri-collection('?select=sample-*.xml')"/>

    <xsl:param name="start-id" as="xs:integer" select="35000"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" streamable="yes" use-accumulators="element-count"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="element-count" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="*" select="$value + 1"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:iterate select="$input-uris ! doc(.)">
            <xsl:param name="start-id" select="$start-id"/>
            <xsl:result-document href="updated-xmls/{tokenize(document-uri(), '/')[last()]}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
                    <xsl:with-param name="start-id" select="$start-id" tunnel="yes"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:result-document>
            <xsl:next-iteration>
                <xsl:with-param name="start-id"
                    select="$start-id + accumulator-after('element-count')"/>
            </xsl:next-iteration>
        </xsl:iterate>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:param name="start-id" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="collection-count"
                select="$start-id + accumulator-before('element-count')"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

No streaming yet as I am currently not sure how to hand on the value from a streamed document, will see whether I can resolve that later. But streaming would require Saxon EE, anyway.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to implement this code. Don't you know Microsoft's SSIS supports XSLT 3.0?

Comment: Microsoft's own XSLT processors, like the various MSXML versions and the .NET ones like XslCompiledTransform, only support XSLT 1.0. I have no idea whether SSIS allows plugging in an XSLT 2 or 3 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime or Altova Raptor.

Comment: which free software XSLT tool to deal with many files you would reccomend then (with 3.0 support).

Comment: Saxon 9.9 HE is available for the .NET platform (on NuGet and Sourceforge) and the Java platform (on Maven and Sourceforge) as well as in a C/C++ version with PHP and Python bindings to use XSLT 3.

Comment: As Martin Honnen already pointed out, SSIS out-of-the-box supports just XSLT v.1.0 Though SSIS Script Task allows to launch any .Net code. So combination of Saxon 9.9 .Net edition and SSIS Script Task will provide a solution.